# How to create json in datatables into codeigniter view

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter-3

can you help me, 
error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

```
    <tbody>
          <tr>
            <?php 
              $dataSiswa   = json_decode($dataSiswa);
              if($semuaSiswa > 0){
                $i=0;
                foreach ($dataSiswa as $myData) {
                  $id_siswa   = $myData->id_siswa;
                  $kelas      = $myData->id_kelas;
                  $kelas      = getKelas($kelas);   
                  $nama       = $myData->nama;
                  $alamat     = $myData->alamat;

                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?=$id_siswa;?></td>
                    <td><?=$kelas;?></td>
                    <td><?=$nama;?></td>
                    <td><?=$alamat;?></td>

                    <td><a href="<?=site_url('siswa/hapus/'.$id_siswa);?>" onclick="return confirm('Hapus data ini ?');">Hapus</a></td>
                  </tr>
            <?php} }?>
            </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and script javascript `$('#siswa').dataTable();`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the solution >> [check this out](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32575/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined)